# Помогите доработать и найти ошибку

Tags: java, массивы

Всем привет, в общем такое дело. Нужно написать код, который сортирует массив по алгоритму Shell и сохраняет изначальную позицию слова в несортированном массиве чтобы по надобности указать позицию, которую занимало слово до сортировки.

Код с введением одномерного массива и созданием двумерного массива с позицией слова в нем -

```
 public static String [][] sortInZweid(String[] array){
        String[][] arrN = new String [array.length][2];
        int counterForIndex = 1;
        int counterForString = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                arrN[i][counterForString] = array[i];
                arrN[i][counterForIndex] = Integer.toString(i);
        }
        return arrN;
     }
Код, который нужно переписать чтобы метод принимал двумерный массив и сохранял после сортировки позицию слова в несортированном массиве. Например - 
                                           "Borija" , "1";
                                           "Dima" , "2";
                                           "Anna" , "3";
После сортировки должно выглядеть так -    "Anna" ,"3";
                                           "Borija" , "1";
                                           "Dima" , "2";
```

Код который нужно переписать -

```
int sort(String [] arr) {
        for (int gap = arr.length / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) {
            for (int i = gap; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
                final String temp = arr[i];
                int j;
                for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap].compareTo(temp) > 0; j -= gap) {
                    arr[j] = arr[j - gap];
                }
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Код который переписал я, но он работает неправильно, разбираю целый день, но не могу понять почему -

```
int sort(String [][] arr) {
        for (int gap = arr[0].length / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) {
            for (int i = gap; i < arr[0].length; i += 1) {
                final String temp = arr[i][0];
                final String index = arr[i][1];
                int j;
                for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap][0].compareTo(temp) > 0; j -= gap) {
                    arr[j] = arr[j - gap];
                }
                arr[j][0] = temp;
                arr[j][1] = index;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `arr[j] = arr[j - gap];`?

Comment: @tym32167 // shift earlier gap-sorted elements up until the correct location for a[i] is found 
            int j;             
            for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap) 
                arr[j] = arr[j - gap];

Comment: @tym32167 Код можно посмотреть полностью разложенный тут https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shellsort/

Comment: я ничего не понял. Если вы хотите сохранить индексы, зачем вы их перезаписываете? `arr[j][1] = index;`

Comment: @tym32167 Я хочу чтобы со словом был закреплен и индекс, иначе получатся просто сортированные слова с новыми индексами, а мне нужно по заданию сохранить старые индексы у слов. Например, слово "Якоб" находится первым в массиве имеет индекс "0", а после сортировки будет последним в массиве с индексом "0". поэтому я создал двумерный массив чтобы создать словам индексы и этот двумерный массив должен быть отсортирован, но второй столбик строки должен остаться неизменным, а именно тот, где стоит индекс.

Comment: @tym32167 Тоесть индекс должен сохраняться за словом при перемещении слова в двумерном массиве.

Comment: `Если вы хотите сохранить индексы, зачем вы их перезаписываете? arr[j][1] = index;`

Comment: @tym32167  При смене словом позиции в массиве я перезаписываю закрепленный индекс за этим словом на новое место или этого не нужно делать и индекс автоматически сохранится при сортировке слова?

Comment: Почему не `final String[] temp = arr[i]; ... arr[j] = temp;` ? Также, вы пишете, что у вас что то работает не правильно - опишите подробней, что именно не правильно?

Comment: @tym32167 метод не сортирует после таких изменений. Заменяется только первый элемент, на втором поле он же дублируется почему-то и все остальные элементы остаются несортированными

Comment: `for (int i = gap; i < arr[0].length; i += 1) {` => `for (int i = gap; i < arr.length; i += 1) {` ?

Comment: @tym32167 тогда же будет работать со строкой, а не с столбцом? Я хочу чтобы у каждого слова в столбце был индекс, но можно попробовать сделать наоборот, что будет строка и во втором столбце по строке индекс, но это все равно нужно будет пободным образом делать как выше.. проблема в том, как переписать слово сразу с индексом

Comment: вы что то путаете. Сейчас у вас массив массивов - то есть у вас X элементов, каждый элемет состоит из 2 частей - строки и индекса. Вот это  -`arr[0].length` берет первый элемент и смотрит его длину - она равна 2, так состоит из слова и его индекса. Вот это `arr.length` - вернет общее количество элементов. Вы не спорьте со мной, проверьте просто поменяв свой код как я вам подсказал.

Comment: @tym32167 Хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @tym32167 Тогда получается вот это - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2

Comment: @tym32167 Да, ты оказался прав, я просто опечатался и поэтому ошибку дало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы совсем не читаете, что вам пишут в комментариях.

1. Заменить в циклах `arr[0].length` => `arr.length`
2. `String[] temp = arr[i]; ... arr[j] = temp;`

Получится в итоге

```
static int sort(String [][] arr) {
    for (int gap = arr.length / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) {
        for (int i = gap; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
            String[] temp = arr[i];
            int j;
            for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap][0].compareTo(temp[0]) > 0; j -= gap) {
                arr[j] = arr[j - gap];
            }
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

И все нормально сортируется

```
[Anna, 2]
[Borija, 0]
[Dima, 1]
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь)

Comment: Пожалуйста, на здоровье!

Answer (score 1):

Если тебе нужны исходные индексы слов, просто перед сортировкой создай словарь:

слово -> индексы в неотсортированном массиве.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> indices = new HashMap<>();
```

Нет смысла городить тут двумерные массивы.
Сам алгоритм сортировки можно оставить без изменений.

Или же сортировать не строки а пары

```
Pair<String, Integer> = ImmutablePair.of(arr[i], i);
```

Можно создать и свой класс  StringAndIndex,  учитывая при сравнении внутри алгоритма сортировки только сами строки.

```
class StringAndIndex {
    int index;
    String str;
    public StringAndIndex(String str, int idx) {
         this.index = idx;
         this.str = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Словарь не поможет, если слова будут повторяться. Сортировка парами по сути то ж самое, что сортировка массива. Я к тому, что ваше предложение имеет смысл, но оно не отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @lisyara Да, слова будут дублироваться.. В этом и проблема(

Comment: словарь содержит СПИСОК индексов на каждое слово а не один индекс как раз на случай повторов слова.

Comment: @lisyara я попробую, а с классом как можно было бы сделать, мог бы ты пример прислать или обьяснить?

Comment: @Str добавил класс - самый обыкновенный pojo, проще не бывает)

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне, то идея с созданием класса лучше, чем двухмерный массив. Последнее - совсем костыль.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class ShellSort {

    int sort(Pair arr[]) {        
        for (int gap = arr.length / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) {
            for (int i = gap; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
                final Pair temp = arr[i];
                int j;
                for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap].compareTo(temp) > 0; j -= gap) {
                    arr[j] = arr[j - gap];
                }
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String arr[] = {"xxx", "aaa", "ccc", "bbb", "zzz"};
        System.out.println("Array before sorting");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        ShellSort ob = new ShellSort();
        Pair[] array = Pair.of(arr);
        ob.sort(array);

        System.out.println("Array after sorting");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}


class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{

    private final int index;
    private final String name;

    public Pair(Integer index, String name) {
        this.index = index;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "->" + index;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair pair) {
        return this.name.compareTo(pair.getName());
    }

    public static Pair[] of(final String[]arr){
        final Pair[] pairs = new Pair[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) pairs[i] = new Pair(i, arr[i]);
        return pairs;
    }

}
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, попробую с двумерным и если слишком сложно будет, то сделаю класс по Вашему примеру )